# Printing the value of a property

Tags: c++, qt

I want to print the value of a QProperty.

```
QDebug << node->metaObject()->superClass()->property(i).name();
QDebug << node->metaObject()->superCalss()->property(i).read(node)
```

However read returns a `QVariant` altough I just want to get the value as string.

How to do that?

```
   QDebug << QVariant::toString(node->metaObject()->superCalss()->property(i).read(node));
```

doesn't work BTW

I'm new to Qt BTW

Comment: maybe `QVariant::toString()`?

Comment: lets try that @tobi303

Comment: btw you get the answer faster if you do the [rtfm](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) instead of letting others do it for you :P

Comment: @tobi303 it says "undefined reference of toString"

Comment: because `toString` isnt static

Comment: so I need to do what? @tobi303

Comment: you need to read [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) that has a nice example on how to get a string from a variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
node->metaObject()->superCalss()->property(i).read(node).toString()
```